# What is the use of SlugField in django?

Tags: django, django-models

Note: Please dont consider it as duplicate post, all the existing posts are not giving clear understanding of SlugField.

My question is "we can sluggify and store the value in a CharField right? then why do we need SlugField for something that can be done easily using CharField?"

For example, in my model, I have a field called

```
url = models.CharField(max_length=30)
def save(self, ...):
    self.url = slugify(self.url)
    .......
```

Won't the url be saved in slugified format in database? I can use this slugified value in browser right, then what is the use of creating models.SlugFIeld(max_length=30)? What advantage SlugField will add over slugified CharField?

In above code, how replacing "CharField" with "SlugField" be advantageous?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

> We can `slugify` and store the value in a CharField right? then why do we need SlugField for something that can be done easily using `CharField`?

A `SlugField` is a `CharField`, but a special `CharField`. It is a field that contains a *validator* that will, if you for example enter data through a form, validate if the entered string is indeed a slug. For example a slug does not contain whitespace, so if you would use the `SlugField` in a form, such that an author can specify the slug themselve, it will reject such slugs.

By default it uses the [**`django.core.validators.validate_slug`** validator <sup>[GitHub]</sup>](https://github.com/django/django/blob/stable/3.1.x/django/core/validators.py#L227-L232). The `SlugField` has an extra parameter `allow_unicode`. If this is set to `True`, it will use the [**`django.core.validators.validate_unicode_slug`** validator <sup>[GitHub]</sup>](https://github.com/django/django/blob/stable/3.1.x/django/core/validators.py#L235-L239).

So in essence it is indeed a `CharField`, but with a validator that is determined by the [**`allow_unicode=…` parameter <sup>[Django-doc]</sup>](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/stable/ref/models/fields/#django.db.models.SlugField.allow_unicode). This thus makes it more convenient.

Often you do not want to slugify the content of the slug field itself, but from another field, for example the title of a blog post entry. You thus still want to preserve the title, but make a slugified variant.

The [**`django-autoslug`** package <sup>[readthedocs]</sup>](https://django-autoslug.readthedocs.io/en/latest/) provides an [**`AutoSlugField`** <sup>[readthedocs]</sup>](https://django-autoslug.readthedocs.io/en/latest/fields.html#autoslug.fields.AutoSlugField) which is more convenient, since you can define how to populate the field, and thus it will automatically slugify:

```
from autoslug import AutoSlugField

class MyModel(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=128)
    slug = AutoSlugField(populate_from='title')
```